# Spirit: Not able to use x3::skip(skipper)[some recursive rule] in its rule definition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

Let's say we want to parse a recursive block like this. When "`skip_comments_tag`" is prefixed to the block, we skip all comments(`/*...*/`) within this block recursively.

```
{
    {}
    {
        skip_comments_tag{
            {} /*comments*/ 
            { /*comments*/ } 
        }
    }
}
```

It's easy to come up with a recursive parser as in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31fb17064091fae3).

```
namespace Parser {
    auto const ruleComment = x3::lit("/*") >> *(x3::char_ - "*/") >> "*/" | x3::space;

    x3::rule<struct SBlockId> const ruleBlock;
    auto const ruleBlock_def = x3::lit('{') >> *(ruleBlock | "skip_comments_tag" >> x3::skip(ruleComment)[ruleBlock]) >> '}';

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(ruleBlock)
}
```

But it doesn't compile (when the `parse` function is called) because it will generate an infinite context (by `x3::make_context` in `x3::skip_directive`). `x3::no_case` and `x3::with` also have this problem because they all use `x3::make_context` in the implementation.

Questions:

1. Is there always a better way to write parsers for this kind of
   questions to avoid such compile error and how?
2. Or is the `x3::make_context` implementation considered to be flawed for this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I do think this is a limitation in the `make_context` facility, and yes, it has bitten me before.

You might be able to skirt it by using TU separation (`BOOST_SPIRIT_DECLARE`, `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` and 
`BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE` macros).

Honestly, I'd report it at the mailing list: [spirit-general]

See also http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Horrible-compiletimes-and-memory-usage-while-compiling-a-parser-with-X3-td4689104i20.html (FWIW I feel the "sequence partitioning" issue is unrelated)